# Why is passing a dataset to a web service method not good?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, wcf

Please explain in detail. I have been telling my mentor that everything I've researched on WCF and many programmers all over the net say it is NOT good to pass DataSets to the service, why is that? I created a BUNCH of classes in the service and the work great with the application, but he says that I just wasted time doing all that work, he has a better way of doing it.

He keeps telling me to create a SINGLE OperationContract. There will be many functions in the service, but the OperationContract will take the string name of the function and the dataset providing the details for that function.

Is his way bad practice? Not safe? I'm just trying to understand why many people say don't use datasets.

Comment: Something interesting to read:[WebServices is the Spawn of Satan and Represents All That Is Truly Evil in the World](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ReturningDataSetsFromWebServicesIsTheSpawnOfSatanAndRepresentsAllThatIsTrulyEvilInTheWorld.aspx)

Comment: From a pragmatic standpoint, if this service is created for consumption by a single application, which you also control, then using DataSets could be viewed as being fine. However if there is a chance that there would be other consumers (whether .NET or not), don't do it.

Comment: You really should ask your mentor about this and evaluate the truth of his explanation yourself to not disturb your relationships' integrity. It is not mine to judge but the best way to question superiors' or mentors' advice is the direct one.

Comment: @user469104, Yes, the service is for consumption by ONLY 1 application from all the users. So then it IS fine, just for this kind of scenario then?

Comment: @Gmac - whether that is fine for your situation is something you and your organization will have to determine but from my viewpoint, yes, if it is for a situation where the service has one consumer, and the same people maintain both the client and the server code, then using a dataset would not be the end of the world.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first reason is interoperability. If you expect consumers of your service to be implemented in any other technologies other than .NET, they may have lots of trouble extracting or generating the data in the DataSet, as they will have no equivalent data structure on their end.

Performance can be affected quite a bit, as well. In particular, the serialization format for untyped datasets can be huge because it will contain not just the data, but also the XSD schema for the data set, which can be quite large depending on the complexity of the DataSet. This can make your messages a lot larger, which will use more network bandwidth, take longer to transfer (particularly over high latency links), and will take more resources at the endpoint to parse.

Answer (score 0):

So the web service you have does something specific lets say it sends a bunch of emails. Lets say this service has one method that sends an email. The method should accept and email address, subject and a body.

Now if we send a data set with the information required the service would have to know the shape of the data and parse it.

Alternatively if the web service accepted a object with properties for email address, subject and body. It can be used in more than one place and is less prone to going wrong dues to a malformed dataset.

Answer (score 0):

One more thing: you can get incorrect data using DataSet.

> For example a value in the DataSet might look like the following before serialization:
>
> `<date_time>12:19:38</date_time>`
>
> In the client it would come with a offset specified:
>
> `<date_time>12:19:38.0000000-04:00</date_time>`
>
> The client code would adjust this to its local time (much like Outlook when you schedule an appointment with someone in a different timezone).

More details can be found [here](http://ratborg.blogspot.nl/2011/06/datetime-serialization-issue-within.html).

Answer (score 0):

Using WCF is not just an implementation decision - it is a design choice.  When you choose to use WCF you have to abandon many of your treasured OO principles behind and embrace a new set of patterns and principals that are associated to service orientation.

One such principle is that of explicit contracts:  A service should have **well defined** public contracts (see [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-oriented_architecture)).  This is crucial for interoperability, but is also important so clients have an accurate picture of what functionality your service provides.

A DataSet is basically just a big bag of "stuff" - there is no limitation to what it could contain - or any well defined contract that explains how I can get data out.  By using a DataSet you introduce inherent coupling between the client and the server - the client has to have "inside information" about how the DataSet was created in order to get the data out.  By introducing this level of coupling between the client and service you have just negated one of the main motivations for using WCF (precisely that of decoupling the two areas of functionality to allow for independent deployment and/or development lifecycle).